# Is the dell u2713h fully compatible with the late mac mini 2012 using mavericks?

Tags: macos, mac

I'm sure some of you guys have experience with this setup. I'm learning how to program iOs. I did find a lot of topics that the mac mini i7 is powerful enough to compile in Xcode.

My problem however is the following. On the macfora I've read that problems may arise connecting a dell u7213h to a late mac mini 2012. They even talk about performing a hack in terminal to change the edid of the dell u2713h. Some also talk about problems waking up out of sleeping etc. Others say they don't have any problems.

Moneywise I'd prefer to buy a mac mini over an iMac. However, I don't want to have any compatiblity problems. I already own a dell u2713h and a logitech webcam c910. I also know apple released a beta version of macOs solving some graphics problems. Maybe that will work out?

So does the dell u2713h looks awesome in 2560*1440 mode connected to a mac mini 2012 using mini displayPort to thunderbold? Would the logitech work decently by the way?

If you have the same setup: please share your experiences !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I've got a u2713hm connected to my late '12 macbook pro. I fixed it with a custom EDID file. Note that you do not change the EDID of the monitor. There is some stuff going on on forums which involve a ruby script. I played around a bit and ended up with an EDID file. Because i install my mac every now and then, i keep a log file of all the hacks i did. My log file says i did this to get the monitor working in RGB mode. This is for a dell u2713 **hm** monitor though.

> wget
>   http://embdev.net/attachment/167830/U2713H_U2713HM_Mac_EDID_override.zip
>
> unzip U2713H_U2713HM_Mac_EDID_override.zip
>
> sudo mv DisplayVendorID-10ac /System/Library/Displays/Overrides

I do have wake up problems every now and then. Its a macbook though, dont know for the mac-mini. I connected my monitor with minidisplayport. I found out it might help to connect power to my macbook first, then plugin the keyboard and then the minidisplay port. I keep the lid closed while doing it.

This is the forum thread i was talking about: http://embdev.net/topic/284710

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently writing this answer on my iMac Mini with Dell U2713H monitor.

The key is:

1. Use the DisplayPort to MiniDP cable (MiniDP can plug into ThunderBolt port).
2. Configure the Monitor to use RGB color, PC Gamma, DisplayPort 1.2